# How to Delete message using AlertDialogBox from api response in Adapter class

Tags: android, adapter

I'm working on a messaging application.Now in conversation activity I want to make a option for sender can delete his/her message.I do it with a button and its working fine. The problem is I want to do it with an alertDialogBox. When sender long press on his message then an dialog box will open and he can delete that specific message.As I'm using retrofit what can I do for the deleting the message by this way?

Here is my custom adapter class:

```
public class Single_chat_adapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter{

private static final int VIEW_TYPE_MESSAGE_SENT = 1;
private static final int VIEW_TYPE_MESSAGE_RECEIVED = 2;


private Context mContext;
private List<Datum2> data;
private  String userID;

private UserAuthenticationKey userAuthenticationKey;
private SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
private SharedPreferences.Editor editor;


public Single_chat_adapter(Context mContext, List<Datum2> data, String userID) {
    this.mContext = mContext;
    this.data = data;
    this.userID = userID;
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return data.size();
}


// Determines the appropriate ViewType according to the sender of the message.
@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    Datum2 message = (Datum2) data.get(position);

    if (message.getOriginatorId().equals(userID)) {
        // If the current user is the sender of the message
        return VIEW_TYPE_MESSAGE_SENT;
    } else {
        // If some other user sent the message
        return VIEW_TYPE_MESSAGE_RECEIVED;
    }
}
// Inflates the appropriate layout according to the ViewType.
@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(final ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    View view;
    if (viewType == VIEW_TYPE_MESSAGE_SENT) {
        view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.item_message_sent, parent, false);
        return new SentMessageHolder(view);

    } else if (viewType == VIEW_TYPE_MESSAGE_RECEIVED){
        view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.item_message_received, parent, false);
        return new ReceivedMessageHolder(view);
    }
    return null;
}
// Passes the message object to a ViewHolder so that the contents can be bound to UI.
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    Datum2 message = (Datum2) data.get(position);

    switch (holder.getItemViewType()) {
        case VIEW_TYPE_MESSAGE_SENT:
            ((SentMessageHolder) holder).bind(message);

            break;
        case VIEW_TYPE_MESSAGE_RECEIVED:
            ((ReceivedMessageHolder) holder).bind(message);
    }

    holder.itemView.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(final View view) {

            return false;
        }
    });

}

// Sent message view holder
private class SentMessageHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    TextView messageText, timeText;
    ImageButton iB;
    MsgDltAPIService msgDltAPIService;
    String rec_id;
    String content_id;
    final int[] ids = new int[100];

    SentMessageHolder(final View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        messageText = itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_message_body);
        timeText = itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_message_time);
        iB = itemView.findViewById(R.id.sentMessageTextDelete);
        msgDltAPIService = RestClient.getClient().create(MsgDltAPIService.class);

        iB.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                userAuthenticationKey = new UserAuthenticationKey(mContext.getApplicationContext());
                sharedPreferences =  mContext.getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("user authentication", MODE_PRIVATE);
                editor = sharedPreferences.edit();

                ids[0] = Integer.parseInt(content_id);

                if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(content_id) && TextUtils.isDigitsOnly(content_id)) {
                    ids[0] = Integer.parseInt(content_id);
                } else {
                    ids[0] = 0;
                }
                final MsgDltRequest msgDltRequest = new MsgDltRequest(
                        ids,
                        rec_id);
                Call<MsgDltResponse> call =
                        msgDltAPIService.msgDlt(userAuthenticationKey.getUserTokenKey(),
                                msgDltRequest);
                call.enqueue(new Callback<MsgDltResponse>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(Call<MsgDltResponse> call, Response<MsgDltResponse> response) {

                        Toast.makeText(mContext.getApplicationContext(), "message deleted",
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(Call<MsgDltResponse> call, Throwable t) {
                        Toast.makeText(mContext.getApplicationContext(), "please try again",
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }

    void bind(Datum2 message) {
        messageText.setText(message.getMsg());

        // Format the stored timestamp into a readable String using method.
        timeText.setText(message.getCreatedAt().getFormatTime());
        content_id = message.getContentId().toString();
        if (! message.getOriginatorId().equals(userID)){
            rec_id.valueOf(message.getOriginatorId());
        }
        else {
            rec_id = null;
        }
    }

}

// Received message view holder
private class ReceivedMessageHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    TextView messageText, timeText, nameText;
    //        ImageView profileImage;
    HexagonImageView profileImage;

    ReceivedMessageHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        messageText = itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_message_body);
        timeText = itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_message_time);
        nameText = itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_message_name);
        profileImage = itemView.findViewById(R.id.image_message_profile);
    }

    void bind(Datum2 message) {
        messageText.setText(message.getMsg());

        // Format the stored timestamp into a readable String using method.
        timeText.setText(message.getCreatedAt().getFormatTime());
        nameText.setText(message.getOriginator().getFullName());

        // Insert the profile image from the URL into the ImageView.
        Glide.with(mContext).load("myweburl" + data.get(getLayoutPosition())
                .getOriginator().getAvatar()).apply(RequestOptions.circleCropTransform())
                .into(profileImage);
    }
}
}
```

I set a button named **iB** by which I can delete the message. But unfortunately I failed to do it by using an alertBox.

Answer (score 0):

In your on long pressed listener, pass the message object to the parent activity/adapter using listener and then from parent open a dialog box passing the object to it, now when deleting your data simply remove the message from the `List<Datum2> data` and notify adapter

```
public class SingleChatAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter {
 // ...
 //... 
 @Override
 public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
   Datum2 message = (Datum2) data.get(position);
   switch (holder.getItemViewType()) {
    case VIEW_TYPE_MESSAGE_SENT:
     ((SentMessageHolder) holder).bind(message);
     break;
    case VIEW_TYPE_MESSAGE_RECEIVED:
     ((ReceivedMessageHolder) holder).bind(message);
   }
   holder.itemView.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onLongClick(final View view) {
     mListener.onMessageLongPressed(message);
     return false;
    }
   });
  }
  // ....
  // ...

 // here is the listener interface parent need to implement
 public interface OnChildInteraction {
  public void onMessageLongPressed(Datum2 message);
 }
}
```

a rough implementation in parent will be

```
public class ParentActicvity extends AppCompatActivity implements SingleChatAdapter.OnChildInteraction
@override 
public void onMessageLongPressed(Datum2  message){
  // override delete button listener to call list.remove(message) 
  // notify adapter.
// open dialog

}
```

Comment: I'm really sorry and don't understand where to use interface OnChildInteraction and onMessageLongPressed method. Can you give me a suggestion please?

Comment: also use Java convention while naming your classes

Comment: Thank you for suggestion but still I'm stuck it's not working.